# Slic3r GCode Estimated time to print

Tags: 3d

Can slic3r export the estimated time to print an object in gcode export via the command line?

I've used the `--gcode-comments` option for including a more verbose output but it does not include an estimated time to print.

Comment: This question might be better for this site http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41850/maker-professionals. Unforetunately it hasn't entered beta yet.

Answer (score 1):

No. It requires firmware configuration which it doesn't have access to.

https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/issues/1334

Your host software may. Repetier shows it on the G-Code tab near the bottom (underneath the Visualization tab)